# Cabal: build dir with source

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a `src` directory. In this directory I have `Main.hs` file and `Test` directory. In the `Test` directory I have `Test.hs` module. I need to compile it with cabal.

In my cabal file I have:

```
Executable main
  -- .hs or .lhs file containing the Main module.
      Main-is: src/Main.hs
```

and

```
  -- Modules not exported by this package.
     Other-modules: Test.Test
```

When I do `cabal configure` it's OK, but when I try to `cabal build` I get the following error:

```
cabal build
Preprocessing executables for main-0.0.1...
cabal: can't find source for Test/Test in ., dist/build/autogen
```

How can I correctly build `Main.hs` and some other directories with `.hs` files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If `Test.Test` is defined in `src/Test/Test.hs`, you need

```
hs-source-dirs: src
```

in the Executable section of your Cabal file. Note that your `main-is` file path should be relative to the source directory, so in this case, you should change it to `Main.hs`.