# How can I tell runhaskell that a module is not in the same folder?

Tags: haskell, module, haskell-platform

I want to place a module in a different folder.
Is there a possibility to tell in the import statement the path to the module?
Note I don't want to use cabal, because in the editor I use, runhaskell is the default executable for haskell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cabal: build dir with source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543039/cabal-build-dir-with-source)

Comment: That doesn't seem a very good reason not to use Cabal. Seriously, for any project that's more than a single-file script, Cabal is absolutely the way to go; if your editor doesn't support it then just execute the commands in a seperate terminal. (But also consider switching to a better editor...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-i` flag to define an include dir, for example

```
runhaskell -isrc MyModule
```

Also, if you have a .cabal-file in your project you can invoke `runhaskell` with the same source folder and package configuration via `cabal exec`:

```
cabal exec runhaskell -- MyModule
```